# Creating a block for a header-only library

Tags: c++, boost, biicode

I am trying to convert a header-only library into a block. The library already uses CMake and contains test and example programs. I've gone through biicode documentation but not clear how to create block for existing project. I am confused whether I should do `bii init -L` or `bii cpp:configure`. I tried specifying Boost as requirement in biicode.conf but getting `WARN: Removing unused reference to "biicode/boost: 0"`

Please let me know the steps to create block for existing project, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should start using `bii init -L` inside the library's folder. Then, [following this steps on the docs](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/adapt_library_guide.html#look-for-unresolved-dependencies-with-bii-deps), check for unresolved dependencies with `bii deps` command, adapt biicode.conf file (if needed), and add the external dependencies.

Also adapt your current *CMakeLists.txt* with:

```
IF(BIICODE)
   INCLUDE("biicode.cmake")
   RETURN()
ENDIF()
```

*biicode.cmake* file should at least have `ADD_BII_TARGETS()` in it, as you're depending on Boost, yours should look like the code below, [here's a guide explaining how depend on Boost](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/examples/boost.html).

```
#Include the biicode Boost setup script
include(biicode/boost/setup)

ADD_BII_TARGETS()

#Setup Boost and build (if needed) the required Boost components
#Since lambda is header-only, there are no components to build and find
bii_find_boost()

#Add Boost headers to the block include directories
target_include_directories(${BII_BLOCK_TARGET} INTERFACE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Run `bii find` to retrieve the depencencies and `bii configure` to configure it to your current config and build with `bii build`. Check [common issues building in the docs here](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/adapt_library_guide.html#execute-bii-build).

For issues using boost - [biicode has a boost repository in github](https://github.com/biicode/boost).